# Looking for a solution that can keep my custom navigation bar in focus when the keyboard is also focus

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

My Navigation bar keeps going out of focus once my keyboard is enabled. Looking for a solution that can keep it in focus even when the keyboard is in focus.

> Screenshots
> [image: When Keyboard is not in focus]
> [image: When Keyboard is in focus]

Comment: Which `WindowSoftInputMode` do you have on your Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this

```
[Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
```

in your class attribute.

Or you can do experiment with different enums of the **SoftInput** to meet your requirement.

More on this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility)

Comment: I'm building the app for cross platform so will this issue I'm facing here not also be experienced on the ios side.? Asking coz I've only been able to test my app on android so far.

Comment: Thanks your solution works fine on my android device.